# How to implement input type Password in Google Card Service?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I am creating a form in **App Script using Google card service**. I want to **hide my password** in a **star format like "***"**. However, I am not able to implement this functionality to hide my password. Please guide me on how to implement input type Password in Google Card Service.

**Current behavior**

[image]

**I want this behavior**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible.